# Create a calculated field in quicksight

Tags: date, between, amazon-quicksight

Can someone help me build a formula in quicksight using this condition:

The **SUM** of sale where `Sale_Date` is between `Joined_Date – 30 days and Joined_Date - 1`.

I already have this, but I just cant do the IN BETWEEN DATES.

```
sumIf({Sale}, truncDate('DD', {Sale_Date}) >= addDateTime(30, 'DD', truncDate('DD', {Joined_Date})))
```